# int does not increment in struct when using ++

Tags: c++

I have a struct that contains an int but when I call the following...

```
typedef std::map<char, MessageLetter> Letters;
...
Letters lList;
...
MessageLetter m = lList[letter];
std::cout << "Before " << m.count << std::endl;
int c = ++m.count;
m.count = c;
std::cout << "After " << m.count << std::endl;
```

I am new to C++ and I am guessing this is a pointer issue but the output is...

```
Before 1
After 2
Before 1
After 2
```

I would expect...

```
Before 1
After 2
Before 2
After 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this statement is part of a body of a loop:

```
MessageLetter m = lList[letter];
```

On each iteration of the loop, you're copying a`lList[letter]` into `m`.  Any modifications to `m` will be lost after the loop iteration completes.  You will not modify `lList[letter]`.

If you want to modify `lList[letter]`, you either need to modify it directly, or make `m` a reference to it:

```
MessageLetter& m = lList[letter];
```

If you do not want to modify `lList[letter]`, then you need to move the above assignment outside the loop to someplace above the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the other answer because it was first. Thanks!

Comment: Given check because it won't let me add a section to answer. I will add to question later

Comment: int a = b is setting a's VALUE to b's VALUE
int* a = &b is setting a's VALUE to the ADDRESS of b
int& a = b is setting a's ADDRESS to b's ADDRESS (a is a reference to b)
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/17153/

Answer (score 4):

I think you actually want:

```
MessageLetter & m = lList[letter];
```

Comment: great can you explain what this is doing in a little more detail and I will give the check?

Comment: I'm headed out the door, so I can't do too much detail. It's fine if someone else wants to edit it in here, or in their own answer. But basically it's the difference of copying an object, or looking at a reference to the object that is in the map.